# Pourquoi les adjectifs numéraux cardinaux sont-ils invariables?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, nombres, pluriel, accord

Je me pose cette question suite à une courte discussion entre collègues sur la question :

> Faut-il dire « quatre oreilles » ou « quatres oreilles » ?

Cette question-là a été évidemment très vite résolue catégoriquement par une simple recherche de [quatre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quatre) qui montre bien qu'il est, comme la plupart des autres adjectifs numéraux cardinaux, invariable.

Par contre, je me rends compte que je ne sais pas pourquoi. Y a-t-il une raison à ça ?
Et pourquoi *un*, *vingt* et *cent* font-ils exception à cette règle dans certains cas ?

Comment: Je crois que l'expression « entre quatre yeux » s'éloigne de la règle dès qu'elle est prononcée…

Answer (score 5):

En un sens, les adjectifs numéraux sont variables, c'est juste qu'on utilise très rarement leurs pluriels. 4 oreilles, ce sont *quatre* oreilles ; il n'y a qu'une fois quatre, donc *quatre* est au singulier. On pourrait donc dire que 8 oreilles, ce sont <strike>*deux-quatres* oreilles</strike>, mais le mot pour ce nombre est *huit*. Ceci n'explique pas la bizarrerie suivant laquelle *vingt* et *cent* ne prennent pas la marque du pluriel lorsqu'on leur ajoute un nombre : *quatre-vingts oreilles* mais *quatre-vingt-une oreilles*. Quand à *mille*, il est bien invariable (*deux mille oreilles*).

Comment: Quant à million, milliard, etc. Ce sont des noms. De même que millier d'ailleurs ! On écrit « deux mille oreilles », mais « deux milliers d'oreilles ». Idem pour « un » lorsqu'il est utilisé dans « Les uns et les autres » ou dans « Les unes des journaux ».

Comment: Il y a une confusion entre être pluriel et avoir une marque graphique avec un -s final. Par exemple, cent est pluriel, deux cents est pluriel, mais deux cents porte un -s final pour représenter la liaison audible 200-z avions...